# Webservice callout - BillingState issue

Tags: apex, webservices

I get Account Country and Statename from the remote service via REST API.

In Apex class, State name is verified to check if it is valid picklist value by calling Metadata API.

But I observe an issue with Country - Mexico and Statename - Distrito Federal..

1. Metadata API has valid state names for Country Mexico: "Distrito Federal" and "Federal District"
2. In Account page, if I select country picklist 'Mexico' , state picklist displays only 'Federal District".
3. Remote service, sends the state name "Distrito Federal", my apex class checks if this state is valid. Since this state name is returned from Meta data api, it tries to update the state with 'Distrito Federal"(DML operation on Account), DML operation fails with error messsage "**FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, There's a problem with this state, even though it may appear correct. Please select a state from the list of valid states.: State/Province:** "

**Any idea why State picklist doesn't display "Distrito Federal" on account page, why DML operation is throwing error though medata api says it is valid picklist value ?  Any issues with country state picklist ?**

code:

**Building the map for statecode:**

```
Map<String, String>StateCodeMap = new Map<String, String>();    
fieldResult = User.Statecode.getDescribe();
ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();  
for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){  
    StateCodeMap.put(f.getLabel(), f.getValue());  
}
```

Later in the process, checking if statename(Company.state) sent by remote service is valid or not by checking in the map like below.

```
StateCodeMap.get(Company.state) != null
```

Comment: what does this have to do with web service callout?  Looks more like a locale issue and how you are using metadata api

Comment: @crop1645, pls look into the code above - edited original question

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to format the code into readable format..

Comment: i think the issue is distinction between display value and integration value for the state picklist - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_integ_values.htm&language=en_US Your map is keyed by display value but you need to update the database with the integration value. BTW, you're not using the metadata API directly, you are using Apex Describe to obtain metadata